# Find $a$ and $b$ such that the improper integral converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Find $a$ and $b$ so that the integral $$\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{(x-1)^a(1+x^2)^b}\, dx$$ converges.

---

I know that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}$ converges if $p>1$ and I've tried integration by parts but neither has helped. Can someone give me a hint as to how I should approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{(x-1)^a(1+x^2)^b}\, dx=\int_1^2 \frac{x}{(x-1)^a(1+x^2)^b}\, dx+\int_2^\infty \frac{x}{(x-1)^a(1+x^2)^b}\, dx$$

and

$$\int_1^2 \frac{x}{(x-1)^a(1+x^2)^b}\, dx=\int_0^1 \frac{y+1}{y^a(y^2+2y+2)^b}\, dy$$

which converges for $a<1$ since as $y \to 0^+$

$$ \frac{y+1}{y^a(y^2+2y+2)^b} \sim\frac1{y^{a}}$$

and

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{x}{(x-1)^a(1+x^2)^b}dx, \quad \frac{x}{(x-1)^a(1+x^2)^b}\sim\frac1{x^{a+2b-1}} \quad x\to \infty$$

converges for $a+2b-1>1 \iff b>1-\frac a 2$.

Therefore the given integral converges for $a<1$ and $b>1-\frac a 2$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the algebra when you switch from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Just take $y=x-1 \implies dx =dy \implies 1+x^2=y^2+2y+2$.

Comment: Oh, right. And the limits conveniently becomes 0 and 1.

Comment: @Timber Yes, it always a good idea refer the integral to $0$ or $\infty$ in these cases.